# Is it possible in SSL handshake where client only send its certificate(one way authentication). Server need not to send any certificate?

Tags: sockets, ssl, tcp, cryptography

Is it possible in SSL/TLS handshake where client only send its certificate. Server need not to send any certificate ?As of now in one way handshake only server send its certificate to client.
As i am aware of that in this scenario server needs to maintain all clients root certificate(if diffrent).This is not practical.If possible what are the security concerns.

Here is context under Use of SSL with socket programming in C# or C++ 
Thanks for help!

Comment: No, it's not possible. I can't see any scenario where it would make sense either.

Comment: Thanks for reply .But my client want that. Any valid reason because he can use same root certificate throughout their client machines.Are there any security concerns ?

Comment: Somewhere along the way either you, or your client, or both, has become confused. I don't think you're using the phrase "root certificate" in its intended meaning.

Comment: let me clearify and please let me know if i am wrong .If we want to achive client authentication only .So client will send its client certificate and server will varify this certificate if server has either root certificate or intermediate  certificate.                                                          thanks for your quivk reply.

Comment: more clearly server must  have root or intermediate certificate corresponding to client in its certificate store for autheticate the CLIENT certificate

Comment: It's not possible, ssl requires that the server be authenticated. There is no reason *not to* authenticate the server.

Comment: yes i know this is standard .Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use SSL/TLS without a server certificate.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38589/can-https-server-configured-without-a-server-certificate

You need software that supports at least one of the anonymous cipher suites [SSL/TLS supports](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml), such as `TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`.  Per [the OpenSSL Diffie Hellman wiki entry](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie_Hellman#Diffie-Hellman_in_SSL.2FTLS):

> **Anonymous Diffie-Hellman** uses Diffie-Hellman, but without authentication. Because the keys used in the exchange are not
>   authenticated, the protocol is susceptible to Man-in-the-Middle
>   attacks. Note: if you use this scheme, a call to
>   `SSL_get_peer_certificate` will return `NULL` because you have selected an
>   anonymous protocol. This is the only time `SSL_get_peer_certificate`
>   is allowed to return NULL under normal circumstances.
>
> You should not use Anonymous Diffie-Hellman. You can prohibit its use
>   in your code by using "!ADH" in your call to `SSL_set_cipher_list`.

Note that support for such cipher suites and configurations in most available SSL/TLS software is either non-existent or very limited, as such configurations are vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks - one of the very things SSL/TLS is used to prevent.  You'd have to compile your own OpenSSL code, for example.

Unless you control the software at both ends of your communication channel(s), effectively there's no way to implement such a system.

And there's no real *reason* to implement such a system as it's not secure at all.

But you *can* do it with a lot of effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew Its making sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Server Certificate which contains the public key part of its key pair is must. The client may decide to overlook the authenticity of the certificate( Its bad!) but the TLS handshake requires the public key for the generation of pre-master-secret. So no way you can prevent server from sending the certificate.

Server if it wishes can request client for its certificate. This is for authenticating the client.

Comment: Hi Prabhu,                                                                                        thanks for reply ! But if you see client also has public key so that also can be utilize for handshake messages  encryption as well as for pre-master key generation.

Comment: No Mohit. TLS protocol defines how to derive the symmetric key for the data encryption. That procedure requires server's public key.

Comment: Thanks Prabhu!  Above answer making sense for me .If you are not feeling this one is correct please let me know

Comment: Andrew's answer is the one which actually provides what you are looking for, Mohit. You should accept Andrew's answer.  You can up-vote mine if you felt you learned something new.